# Postgres query to find all the matching fields from json/jsonb

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```json
[
  {
    "id": "234",
    "name": "JCR",
    "self": "https://jira.abc.io/jira/rest/api/2/component/234"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "React",
    "self": "https://jira.abc.io/jira/rest/api/2/component/123"
  }
]
```

Need values of field 'name'/find all the name matching where clause

Comment: Note that Postgres 9.5  is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible. Especially as it only has very limited JSON support.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the desired result as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). Do you want multiple rows returned?  A single row with a single column and a modified JSON value? Something else?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name does not matter.. I need to find field has name 'React'

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT '[{"id": "234", "name": "JCR", "self": "https://jira.abc.io/jira/rest/api/2/component/234"}, {"id": "123", "name": "React", "self": "https://jira.abc.io/jira/rest/api/2/component/123"}]'::jsonb val
)
SELECT  el
FROM jsonb_array_elements((SELECT val FROM data)) el
WHERE el @> '{"name": "React"}';
```

[db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dJkd5n5v)